# Solana TPU client and sending versioned transactions

Tags: rust, versionedtransactions, solana-client

The solana tpu client (rust) takes a `&Transaction` argument however I deal with `VersionedTransaction`'s.

I would like to know 2 things..

1. How can I send a VersionedTransaction via the tpu client.
2. How can I serialize a VersionedTransaction into base64.

I create the transactions using the solana_sdk like so

```
let message = V0Message::try_compile(
    &wallet.pubkey(),
    &instructions,
    &[],
    block_hash
).unwrap();

let versioned_message = VersionedMessage::V0(message);
let transaction = VersionedTransaction::try_new(versioned_message, &[wallet]).unwrap();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should probably get fixed at the TPU client level, but in the meantime, you can serialize the versioned transaction and use `send_wire_transaction`, ie:

```
tpu_client.send_wire_transaction(bincode::serialize(&transaction).unwrap())
```

Comment: thanks jon, i figured it out earlier hehe - will mark as answer.